# TIMEVALUE setting off a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to have TIMEVALUE set off a script. I have column P which is a Timer column that is subtracting a time from NOW to get a time value and then I am converting that to a TIMEVALUE in column O. When that value is either below or above certain values I want column N to then have a value so it would trigger my checkboxes script. But for some reason I can't get the TIMEVALUE to trigger. I tried to put it in another column and have the values CopyAndPasted Values Only into a column with that run on a time trigger of every minute, but apparently that doesn't count as an Edit or it's not reading the DisplayValue.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  timeValue(e);
  checkboxes(e);
  rangerTime(e);
}

function rangerTime(e){
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn(); 
  if (editColumn === 13 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    const sh = e.range.getSheet();
    sh.getRange(editRow, 25).setValue(sh.getRange(editRow, 25).getValue()+1);
    sh.getRange(editRow, 13).setValue(" ")
  }
}

function timeValue(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn();
  if(editRow > 3) { 
    var rowRange = sheet.getRange("O" + editRow);
    var kCell = sheet.getRange("K" + editRow);
    var kValue = kCell.getValue();
    var nCell = sheet.getRange("N" + editRow);
    var kHasValue = kValue != "";
    if(editColumn > 10) {  
      if(rowRange.getDisplayValue()<0.02 && !kHasValue){
        nCell.setValue(1);
      }
      if (rowRange.getDisplayValue()>0.5 && !kHasValue){ 
        nCell.setValue(1);
      }
      if(kHasValue) { 
        nCell.setValue(" ");
        }
      }
    }
      }

function checkboxes(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  var names = ss.getRange("N4:N");
  var namesValues = names.getValues();
  var checkboxes = ss.getRange("M4:M");
  var cbRows = checkboxes.getHeight();
  var cbValues = checkboxes.getValues();
  var newCBValues = new Array(cbRows); 
  
  for (var row = 0; row < cbRows; row++) {
    newCBValues[row] = new Array(0); 
    if (namesValues[row] == "" || namesValues[row] == " ") { 
      newCBValues[row][0] = " "; 
    }else{ 
      if (cbValues[row][0] === true) {
        newCBValues[row][0] = true; 
      }else{ 
        newCBValues[row][0] = false; 
        
      }   
    }
  }
  checkboxes.setValues(newCBValues); 
}
```

This part is run on the every minute Time Trigger:

```
function CopyandPaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AA4').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O4').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AA4:AA202').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Column AA = TIMEVALUE(Column P)

Comment: I think you are thinking that changing the value of a checkbox with a script will trigger an onEdit() and unfortunately that is not  true.  onEdit trigger are only triggered by user actions.

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> I tried to put it in another column and have the values CopyAndPasted Values Only into a column with that run on a time trigger of every minute, but apparently that doesn't count as an Edit or it's not reading the DisplayValue.

You are right, only actions done by a user directly through the Google Sheets user interface will cause the edit trigger to be triggered.

One option is to make that your time-driven trigger besides changing the checkboxes also call the timeValue function but you have to refactor it or to mock the edit event object to pass it as the timeValue parameter.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Is there a way to do that with what I have here? Cause the checkboxes script is triggered onedit. I just donmt know how to get that one to read the display value even on a timed trigger.